# Sql Select - Total Rows Returned

Tags: sql, go

Using the database/sql package and drivers for Postgres and Mysql I want to achieve the following. I want to be able to Select one row and know that there is either zero rows, one row, or more than one row. the QueryRow function does not achieve that, because as far as I can ascertain, it will return one row without error regardless of if there is more than one row. For my situation, more than one row may be an error, and I want to know about it. I want to create a general function to do this.
I looked at creating a function that uses the Query function, but I do not know how to return the first row if there is more than one row. I want to return the fact that there is more than one row, but I also want to return the first row. To determine that there is more than one row, I have to do a Next, and that overwrites the first row. Obviously I can achieve this without creating a general function, but I want a function to do it because I need to do this in a number of places
Could someone please explain to me how to achieve this. IE. To return the first row from a function when a successful Next has been done or the Next returned nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using both `database/sql` & `MySQLDriver` to achieve this. You can download `MySQLDriver` at https://github.com/go-sql-driver/ .

I wrote `execQuery` function myself to get one or more rows from database. It's based on MySQL but I think it can also used to Postgres with similar implement.

Assume you have a DB table named `test`, and have rows named `id`, `name`, `age`.

Code:

```
var db *sql.DB // it should be initialized by "sql.Open()"

func execQuery(SQL string, args ...interface{}) (rows *sql.Rows, is_succeed bool) {
  rows, err := db.Query(SQL, args...)
  var ret bool
  if err == nil && rows != nil { // if DB query error rows will be nil, it will return false
    ret = true
  } else {
    ret = false
  }

  return rows, ret
}
```

Usage:

```
var name, age string
rows, is_succeed = execQuery("SELECT `name`, `age` FROM `test` WHERE `id` = ?", "123")
if !is_succeed {
  // error
  return 
}
for rows.Next() { // if have zero result rows, this for route won't execute
  err := rows.Scan(&name, &age)
  // check if has error & do something
}
```

If you want to know how much rows returned, just add a counter in `for` route, use SQL can also achieve this.

`sql.Rows` likes a list structure, `rows *sql.Rows` points on first row of returned rows. Use `rows.Next()` to traverse every rows. I think that's what you've asked.

If you really want to know rows count **very** often, using a cache mechanic like `memcacheDB` or `Redis` or just implement a simple counter yourself can help you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want to achieve is essentially to know how many rows are returned. MySql has a way of achieving that (it didn't work for me), however Postgres apparently does not. My second choice is to know if there is more than one row. If there is a second row, the first row is "overwritten" by the Next for second I guess. In summary, what I want to know is all of the following a. Is there one row?, b. Is there more than one row? c. I want the first row regardless. d. Ideally, I would like to know the number of rows, but I think that doing repeated Nexts inefficient.

Comment: Doing a list structure traverse in memory is much more efficient than SQL query. And you can also find answer of all your questions by just several lines of code, which is far more easier than more complicated solutions. However, using `rows.Next()` seems the only solution `database/sql` provides for now, or using cache mechanic.